# How to throw an Apache JMeter keyless token into a variable?

Tags: jmeter

[image]

this works, but how can I ignore the quotation marks in the form of my token "token"
[image]

**i don't want him to get the quotation marks**

Comment: Template `$1$` and Match No. 1

Comment: i tried but it didn't work

Answer (score 1):

I would use [Boundary Extractor](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#Boundary_Extractor)

Put Left and Right Boundary as `"` and you will get the value

> Allows the user to extract values from a server response using left and right boundaries. As a post-processor, this element will execute after each Sample request in its scope, testing the boundaries, extracting the requested values, generate the template string, and store the result into the given variable name

Comment: i found the answer 10 seconds ago, but thank you very much :D

Answer (score 1):

You need to provide the **Template** and specify the [capturing group](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/javaregex/javaregex_capturing_groups.htm) (in your case it will be `1`)

[image]

More information:

- [JMeter: Regular Expressions](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/regular_expressions.html)
- [Using RegEx (Regular Expression Extractor) with JMeter](https://guide.blazemeter.com/hc/en-us/articles/207421325-Using-RegEx-Regular-Expression-Extractor-with-JMeter)

Answer (score 0):

working in this way. maybe you will need it!

[image]